# how to monitor a systemd service

Tags: systemd

I am writing service monitoring app, which needs to know when the services go from active to inactive/failed.

I am subscribing to `PropertiesChanged` signal and watching `ActiveState`.
but this is not sufficient. When a service is stopped using `kill/systemctl stop`, I see that I get `ActiveState=deactivating` changed signal twice: one with `Substate="stop-sigterm"` and another with `Substate="stop-post"`.

As per my previous queries, I understand that only `ActiveState` is considered an API and we should not be looking into `SubState`. but I don't get `ActiveState=inactive` when a service is stopped.

So this seems to be a bug.

For workaround, is there any way to figure out when a service is stopped? As workaround, should I watch `SubState`?

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3807